# need to use scipy.integrate to integrate velocity and predict velocity at every time instant

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

we have an excel file and need to import that to python and use the vel. data and integrate to find the altitude I have a code but my data is way off any idea how to fix it.
the data I have is (falcon9 data excel file):

```
    (Time in s) (Altitude in m) | Velocity in m/s
    -----------------------------------------

    1.   (0s) (0 m)        | 0 m/s
    2. (0.1s) (5.6066 m)   | 0 m/s
    3. (0.2s) (11.1809 m)  | 0.1116 m/s
    4. (0.5s) (27.7602 m)  | 1.2000 m/s
    5.   (1s) (54.7804 m)  | 2.7949 m/s
    6. (1.5s) (80.7522 m)  | 3.9392 m/s
    7.   (2s) (105.4083 m) | 4.8973 m/s
    8. (2.5s) (128.4817 m) | 5.0838 m/s
    9. (2.7s) (137.2080 m) | 5.0883 m/s
   10.   (3s) (149.7050 m) | 5.1960 m/s
```

code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
permit=pd.read_csv(r"C:\---\-----\------\-----data.csv")
permit.dropna()

from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
altitude=integrate.cumtrapz(permit["Velocity in m/s"],permit["Time, in s"],initial=0)
plt.plot(permit["Time, in s"],altitude)
plt.show()

plt.plot(permit["Time, in s"],permit["Altitude in m"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: _but my data is way off_ Can you be more specific? _any idea how to fix it_ Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Is your data strings of floats?

Comment: your data doesn't makes sense. the max velocity is 5.2m/s, yet in 3s, the object travelled 150m? that would put the avg velocity at 50m/s

Comment: Juan can you open the CSV file with a text editor like Notepad and paste the first 10 lines? Excel does automatic formatting depending on your regional settings

Comment: By the way, you should not expose your clients identity as it can be inferred from the file path. It is not relevant for the question.

Comment: when i plot the graphs my predicted values come way off from the actual values.....my predicted looks like a parabola going all the way to the millions while my actual looks like a square root graph not going over the 200k, they stay together almost to the 150s then thats when they completely separate.....I don't know if its supposed to look like that cuz my data seems to be crazy too